# How was this character able to keep fighting effectively in S8E5 of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Towards the conclusion of the episode, we see

> The long awaited Cleganebowl between Sandor and Gregor.

During this fight

> Gregor gouges Sandor's eyes, similar to how he did with Oberyn Martell.

We see them visibly wounded, with blood pouring out, however they still appear to be able to finish the fight. Where would this blood have come from, whilst not robbing

> Sandor

of his vision?

Comment: Did anyone else think the mountain was holding back considering how many times we’ve seen him basically crush a man’s head with his bare hands? Case in point; the ease with which he dispatched Qyburn.

Comment: @Darren he was holding out at least initially because he’s all but invincible. However Qyburn died easily cos he’s not a fighter and fell head first onto some rubble.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Eye gouging does not always lead to blindness, if you've ever played rugby or watched quite a bit of it you'd know it can be common among some players, especially in scrums and rucks and I'd reckon 99% of the time the player can carry on never mind going blind.

[image: Rugby player has his eyes gouged]

Although from watching the scene it is worth noting that after his eyes are gouged he doesn't actually *need* to see. He uses his hands to feel Gregor to find where to stab and when he's free simply runs forward at Gregor rather than anything that requires vision.

Gregor also seemed to be trying to crush Sandor's skull, like with Oberyn, so the full force of the crushing would be applied around the skull rather than solely into the eye sockets.

Comment: In Jiu Jitsu practice I have been on both ends of accidental eye pokes while rolling. Those are clearly less damaging than a deliberate gouge, but in most of those cases we finished the sparring round after a brief pause to check for real serious damage. None of them resulted in permanent damage, much less blindness.